# Wordpress Theme CSS Update Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

i'm working with wordpress v3.6 - theme kallyas v3.1

when I upload/update (via ftp or direct in wordpress) the last version of the theme, the new css files takes affect and works properly

but after I save the settings in the theme option-panel, a few of the css files changes to the old/previous css files immediately

they are constantly being overwritten by the previous one.

i temporarily changed chmod to 777 but i found no way to keep the new css files

any idea for this?

Comment: precise you problem in the title (not just "issue")

Comment: what happens if you upload throw ftp, then change mode to 444 (r-r-r) and then change the settings?